# Incompatible pointer types sending 'PTTouchScene *' to parameter of type 'UIView *'

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uitouch

When I use [touch previousLocationInView], xcode has warning "Incompatible pointer types sending ..."

Why?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
```

```
[super touchMoved:touch withEvent:event];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self]; 
CGPoint preTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];// --> Incompatible pointer types sending PTTouchScene * to parameter of type UIView *
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Is `PTTouchScene` actually a subclass of `SKScene`? (I'm guessing so based on its name and your use of `locationInNode:`)

Be aware that `SKScene` is not a subclass of `UIView`. Instead, `SKView` is a subclass of `UIView` that *has-a* `SKScene`.

That means the fix should be to just pull the view out from the scene using the `-view` method:

`[touch previousLocationInView:self.view];`

Comment: sorry, I do not understand your answer

Comment: You're passing the wrong object to `previousLocationInView:`. Instead of `self`, try passing `self.view`.

Comment: In that case, you probably don't have a `UIView` so you can't use `-previousLocationInView:`. You could store `touchLocation` in a property on your CCScene and use that the next time `touchesMoved:` is called.

Comment: I know. It's a simple way.
But I want to understand why I can call [touch locationInView:self] but can not call [touch previousLocationInView]

Comment: `previousLocationInView:` needs a `UIView` instance, not a `CCScene` instance. It looks like you can get access to the OpenGL view from the `CCDirector` object though, so try `[touch previousLocationInView:[CCDirector sharedDirector].view];`?